# ios - Center Y alignment constraint with dynamic height navigation bar

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom Navigation bar that has dynamic height, I setted a center Y alignment constraint in a view inside a viewcontroller with this custom navigation bar, but the view doesn't go to the correct position when the navigation bar height changes. I need the distance from the top to be 40% of the distance from the bottom of the navigation bar to the bottom of the view controller

I tried the following so far:

- set a constraint from viewcontroller.view to TopLayoutGuide, but Interface Builder won't let me
- create a view inside viewcontroller.view with the constraint to TopLayoutGuide. It worked, but I'm not sure that's the best solution

Is there a better way to do this?